# Spring Tool Suite Not Responding

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

My STS doesn't respond every time I resize a window, click an option that requires a new dialog box popup, or press "Page Up" too many times inside the editor.
My config is as follows:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

I'm using java -version
openjdk version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in the current Eclispse/STS without additional plugins instead of the outdated one (with maybe additional plugins) you have? If yes and if you are on Linux, please tell the GTK version you have.

Comment: The `.ini` file looks like this is on Windows 64bit. But the question about reproducing this in a vanilla STS/Eclipse is important here. Can you double check that? And if you can reproduce this with the latest release and a vanilla install of STS/Eclipse, do you have a sample project that might help to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I moved my code out of the OneDrive folder and that seems to have fixed it! I'll update this question if anything changes. Thank you howlger and Martin Lippert!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the reason and a solution - and thanks for letting us know here.